# Why full specialization of template function is not picked up from the .cpp file without declaration?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, language-lawyer

Following code generate no compilation/linker error/warning:

```
// A.h
#include<iostream>
struct A
{
  template<typename T>
  static void foo (T t)
  {
    std::cout << "A::foo(T)\n";
  }
};
void other ();

// main.cpp
#include"A.h"
int main ()
{
  A::foo(4.7);
  other();
}

// other.cpp
#include"A.h"
template<>
void A::foo (double d)
{
  cout << "A::foo(double)\n";
}

int other ()
{
  A::foo(4.7);
}
```

The output surprisingly is:

```
A::foo(T)
A::foo(double)
```

Why compiler is not able to pick up the correct `A::foo(double)` in case of `main.cpp` ?

Agree that, there is no issue as expected, if there is a declaration in `A.h` like below:

```
template<> void A::foo (double);
```

But that's not the concern, because at link time, compiler has the specialized version.

Also, is having 2 different version of the same function an **Undefined Behavior** ?

Comment: Is that syntax even legal? Shouldn't it be `template <> void A::foo<double>(double d)`?

Comment: @KerrekSB, somehow that syntax is working with g++.

Comment: Hm, maybe that's deducible... interesting. I'd spell it out in any case so as not to confuse the readers...

Comment: With g++, I get different behavior based on whether I compile with optimization or not.  Without optimization, there is no inlining, and the linker chooses one of the two instantiations based on link order.  With optimization, the instantation of the member function of the primary template is inlined in main, so the linker doesn't have a chance to choose.

Comment: @VaughnCato, that's a nice finding, your comment is like an answer. So what I am doing is an Undefined Behavior for sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All explicit specialization declarations must be *visible* at the time of the template instantiation. Since your explicit specialization declaration for `A::foo<double>` is visible in one translation unit but not the other, the program is ill-formed.

(In practice, the compiler will instantiate the primary template in `main.cpp` and the explicitly-specialized one in `other.cpp`. That would still an ODR violation anyway.)

Comment: Shouldn't `ill-formed` program result in compiler/linker error? Also, is this ODR violation a UB when the context is templates.

Comment: @iammilind: I believe that this is not strictly an ODR violation as such, because it's already ill-formed at a conceptually earlier stage. It's just "practically an ODR violation", if you see what I mean. And no, no diagnostic is required for those errors -- obviously! As you just noticed, nobody *can possibly know* that you're going to break the program elsewhere. The code may be inlined in both cases and link fine, just not have the correct behaviour.

Comment: @iammilind: Whether it involves templates or not does not matter: it is undefined behavior. In some cases the linker could actually diagnose the error, but not in all cases for different reasons: if the functions are inlined the different calls will be intermixed with the context in which they were inlined and it would be impossible to pick up the differences. Even if they are not inlined, if both are tagged as `inline` the linker will see two *weak* symbols and won't consider the multiple definition to be an ODR violation, it will randomly pick one and discard the other.

Comment: ... note that `inline` means that finding multiple definitions in the program is not *necessarily* an ODR violation, but if those definitions are not **exactly** the the same it *is* an ODR violation. Currently I know of no compiler with a linker able to catch this form of ODR violation. [**exactly** means that they not only need to match textually, but that all symbols inside the multiple definitions must refer to the same exact elements, i.e. if it calls 'f()', 'f' must resolve to the same symbol in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

`main.cpp` cannot see the code inside `other.cpp`. Template specializations are of file scope.

Answer (score 0):

> Why compiler is not able to pick up the correct A::foo(double) in case of main.cpp ?

The problem is that in a separate compilation model without a declaration available in the header the compiler wouldn't possibly know whether an specialization exists in any translation unit that will later be linked or whether it needs to instantiate the template. The decision in the language is that the absence of a declaration means that there is no manual specialization of the template, and thus the compiler needs to generate one now.

> is having 2 different version of the same function an Undefined Behavior ?

Yes it is. Whether one of the specializations was automatically generated or not, the fact is that it is undefined behavior as it is a violation of the One Definition Rule (there are multiple definitions of the same symbol).